# React-native-elements display all icons as square shape

Tags: react-native, icons, react-native-elements

I'm creating a mobile app using react-native-elements. Whenever I'm using icons in the app, no matter what the icon is, it is displayed as a square. I followed the docs but couldn't get it working.

Here is how it renders icons.

[image]

In the first and second places, I want to place hamburger icon and a search icon respectively, but it is displayed as squares.

**corresponding code**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Header,Text } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

const Menu = (props) => {
    return(
        <Icon
  name='menu' onPress={ () => {
    props.navigation.openDrawer()
}}/>

    )
}

const ActionBar = props => {
    return (
        <Header
        placement="left"
        leftComponent={<Menu navigation={props.navigation}/>}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'OnTask', style: { fontSize: 20,color: '#fff' } }}
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'search', color: '#fff' }}
      />
    );
};

export default ActionBar;
```

Comment: yes, this error occurs when the icon tag cant recognize the icon name in those places. Best would be to download and display it as an image.

Comment: But react-native elements claims that it supports icons through `react-native-vector-icons` and I have installed it also. Can you suggest a way to make it work without downloading all icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at [React Native docs about auto linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#automatic-linking), I came to the conclusion that auto linking works well only with NPM. Since I used Yarn, I ran `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` in the project folder and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

*You need to install `npm install react-native-vector-icons` and import it  like this :*

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

**Look this:** [react-native-elements](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html)

*I use `react-native-vector-icons/Fondisto` for icons. You can find  icons all you want: [Fondisto](https://fontisto.com/icons#brand)*

Comment: I have already installed it. That is why I am so frustrated. I will uninstall and reinstall it and see if it solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the whole icon set you can create your own SVG Components like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg";

type TProps = Readonly<{
  size: number;
  color: string;
}>;

export default class ArrowLeft extends React.PureComponent<TProps> {
    render() {
        const {size, color} = this.props;
        return (
            <Svg
                viewBox="64 64 896 896"
                data-icon="arrowLeft"
                width={size}
                height={size}
                fill={color}
                aria-hidden="true">
                    <Path d="M872 474H286.9l350.2-304c5.6-4.9 2.2-14-5.2-14h-88.5c-3.9 0-7.6 1.4-10.5 3.9L155 487.8a31.96 31.96 0 0 0 0 48.3L535.1 866c1.5 1.3 3.3 2 5.2 2h91.5c7.4 0 10.8-9.2 5.2-14L286.9 550H872c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-60c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8z"></Path>
            </Svg>
        );
    }
}
```

You can check the SVG Path when you inspect the SVG element on the website. Be careful, the copied paths are lowercase the paths component from the library are uppercase.